# Error creating queue in nservicebus

Tags: nservicebus

After some months I am finally back to using nservicebus and started to test it out on a server.  Unfortunately I am getting this exception

```
 The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
```

I've checked using computer manager and the queue does exist and I have granted everybody full control over the queue however this problem persists.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using

```
  var bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                  .SpringBuilder()
                  .XmlSerializer()
                  .MsmqTransport()
                      .IsTransactional(true)
                      .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                  .UnicastBus()
                      .ImpersonateSender(false)
                      .LoadMessageHandlers()
                  .CreateBus()
              .Start();
```

and

```
 <MsmqTransportConfig
  InputQueue="ListenQueue"
  ErrorQueue="error"
  NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
  MaxRetries="5"
  />
```

I works just fine on my dev box.  The full stack trace (which doesn't seem all that useful) looks like

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException was unhandled
  Message=The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
  Source=NServiceListener
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at NServiceListener.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\temp\NServiceListener\NServiceListener\Program.cs:line 35
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I just tried manually creating the queues which also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I'm an idiot and Udi would have solved this in a second had I posted all the required information.  My config file contains

```
<MsmqTransportConfig
  InputQueue="ListenQueue"
  ErrorQueue="error"
  NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
  MaxRetries="5"
  />

  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>

      <add Messages="EnformMessages" Endpoint="EnformMessages" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

As you can see I'm attempting to listen to messages on a non-existent queue called EnformMessages.  Changing that to the InputQueue name or changing the InputQueue name to EnformMessages solved the problem.  I am embarrassed by my stupidity

Comment: I also got this error message when I set .IsTransactional(false), but should have been true